# Getting dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, dpkg

While trying to use `apt-get install`, I'm getting this error `dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.`

[image: SS]

When I'm trying to fix it and use `dpkg --configure -a`, system is freezing on this message

[image: SS1]

Comment: Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1355719/edit) to post text instead of images of terminal.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Also, before the system freezes, can you open system monitor to check if some process is consuming too much memory or CPU cycles? Do you have enough RAM?

Comment: It's ubuntu 20.04 5.4.0-80-generic

Comment: I have 32GB of ram, so its enough